# Fedora: "Login Incorrect"

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, fedora, login

I've just set up a minimal install on my netbook (the default was too resource hungry, so I figured I'd customize the install and learn something about linux at the same time!)

No problems logging in as root, but when I create a new user and try to login as them I just get the "Login incorrect" error. I'm certain the password is correct, though the secure log displays an authentication error. Am I missing a permission somewhere?

`useradd test`
`usermod -p [pwd] test`

Shell is added automatically I think (checking password file says shell is ***/bin/bash***)
I've tried adding the user to the sudo-ers group `usermod -a -G wheel` which doesn't help.
I've kept the password simple in order to rule out human error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: *EDIT: original post edited to clarify, just a typo*

Second: `passwd` is recommended before `usermod -p` (read `man usermod`) (if `passwd` is available on your system, of course, maybe it isn't (though I don't know a mainstream Linux where this isn't the case)).

Third: **`usermod -p` does not take the cleartext password!** Read `man usermod`. If you look in `/etc/passwd`, you'll see the password you entered with `usermod -p` in clear text, but when you try to log in it will be assumed that the password entry is encrypted.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.
Thanks for the suggestions, I'll be able to try them later.

Comment: Wow, now I realise what a silly question that was, using "passwd" solved my problem.
Thanks for your help!